# Hook for pthread_create

Tags: hook, pthreads

Is there (in glibc-2.5 and newer) a way to define a hook for pthread_create?

There is a lot of binary applications and I want to write a dynamic lib to be loaded via LD_PRELOAD

I can add hook on entry to main (''attributte constructor''), but how can I force my code to be executed in every thread just before the thread's function will run.

Answer (score 3):

This answer shows [how to interpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707358/get-all-the-thread-id-created-with-pthread-created-within-an-process/3709027#3709027) pthread_create. (Beware: it will work correctly in 64-bit, but not 32-bit programs.)

Once you interpose pthread_create, you can make it call your own function, which will do whatever you want, and then call the original function the user passed to pthread_create.

Comment: Why this don't work in 32-bit? а если статические приложения нужно инструментировать? Я думал, может есть что по типу malloc_hook